# Saving OpenCV object in memory in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pickle

I am training a face recognition model using Fisher Face algorithm using OpenCV library and Python language.

```
   fisherFace = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()
   fisherFace.train(imagefaceList, np.array(labelsIndexList))
```

I want to save this model in file/memory. In other word i want to save 'fisherface' object. I have tried pickle module for saving this object using [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html). I am not able to pickle and unpickle this object.Code is as below:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
def pickle_test(t):
    print('pickling a test instance...')
        return test, (t.a,)
copyreg.pickle(test, pickle_test)
t = test(f)
t1 = copy.copy(t)
t2 = pickle.dumps(t)
```

Is there any way available that saves trained model for fisher face algorithm and use it at other place by loading same model for face recognition?

Comment: Try using `cv2.FileStorage`. https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/da/d56/classcv_1_1FileStorage.html

Comment: @zindarod Any chance you can unpack that a bit? I am trying to save a kp detector object in the same fashion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474340/python-flask-opencv-how-do-i-cache-an-arbitrary-opencv-object-between-request) but there is a dearth of docs on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FaceRecognizer class has a save method, that stores a xml/yml file into the disk that can be loaded with the load method.

Here is the class method list.

So, you should be able to do

```
fisherFace.save("model.xml")
```

To save model to file.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/face/doc/facerec_api.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am able to save model but I am using opencv 3.3.0 version, which do not directly include save() and load() method in FisherFaceRecognizer class. It is inherited from Algorithm class. So can you help how to load saved model?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would you do this in memory (as per title)?

Answer (score 0):

To save a face recognizer once it has been trained, you can use the write method and save
the state as a yaml or an xml file. 
To use the saved model in the next iteration of the program, call the read method of the recognizer and pass the location of the file where the state was saved.

Comment: How would you do this in memory (as per title)?